# React Create App Integration into PHP + Service Worker

Tags: php, reactjs, service-worker

I'm building a [React Create App](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-app) and can use `npm start` to fire it up in a Browser - this works well - using Webpack, Babel, JSX etc...

I've been asked to integrated this into an existing PHP Solution.

I've run `npm run build` and moved the contents of the build folder into the PHP App and I can navigate to the app in the site after correctly pathing the main js and css...

I now having issue with

> registerServiceWorker.js & service-worker.js.

I attached registerServiceWorker.js but that didn't help.

I think I'm lacking a bit of understanding here. How would I setup a Service Worker in the Php/Web Environment that is already running under React Create App... First time I've worked with Service Workers.

cheers

Comment: You mush integrate service worker and PHP using a webservice. The service worker will call your PHP webservice in background. [Here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/) there is a good tutorial about service workers

Comment: thank-you... appreciated... something new to learn :)